# Is wearing headphones during chess games against the rules in FIDE and Chess.com?

Tags: rules, fide, cheating, chess.com, nakamura

Recently Vladimir Kramnik accused Hikaru Nakamura of cheating in online chess. He Tweeted : "It is impossible to imagine a player to be allowed to wear headphones during a game of chess." Or somethings along the lines of that. But is it actually illegal on chess.com? And also, are the FIDE rules forbidding it?

Comment: For FIDE my understanding is that they are OK to be worn if, *and only if*, they are specifically OK'ed by the arbiter. Relevant rule "11.3.2 During a game, a player is forbidden to have any electronic device not specifically approved by the arbiter in the playing venue." taken from https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012023 . I am not an arbiter, but no arbiter I know would allow such a use.

Comment: As an arbiter, that is accurate. Just to extend this. Generally speaking we don't allow them. I have made exceptions in the past , generally with much younger players (children) , who have a medical condition (eg Developmental Disabilities) which loud environments can be challenging, and if the opponent is happy.  Again, its extremely rare cases that I have seen this / allowed this.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [Comment from Chess.com's Chief Chess Officer](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/ykfc21/comment/iuu0xzp/)

Comment: [Chess.com Official Event Rulebook](https://www.chess.com/article/view/chesscom-event-rulebook), updated Nov 22, 2023, 12:36 PM

Answer (score 6):

According to https://handbook.fide.com/files/handbook/OnlineChessRegulations.pdf

Rule 9.7 states that "Players are not allowed to have headphones in or over their ears during play."

I think that should clear any doubts in your mind. I have also personally played a couple of online chess events and I can definitely say that under no circumstances are you allowed to wear headphones during the match.

As in Hikaru's case, he is basically chess.com's main display man, so I can see why chess.com wouldn't mind him doing whatever he wants. You could say that chess.com literally doesn't care.